# Rails: Order a model by the last element of a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two models: `User` and `Message` that are connected by a `has_many` relationship. I want to get a list of `users` sorted by the timestamp on their last message.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I do this:

```
@users = User.includes(:messages).order('messages.created_at DESC').limit(5)
```

It seems to order the messages, grab the newest 5 messages, and then return the users associated with those. So the number of users can be less than 5. I want to make sure I get the 5 users.

I want the query to get the newest message for each request, order the last messages, and then return the users with the newest messages. So I want something like:

```
@users = User.includes(:messages).order( <messages.last.created_at DESC> )
```

Ideally, the solution would do the sorting on the database, because I want to use paginate. If it's relevant I'm using Postgres.

Comment: have you considered to use `belongs_to` with `:touch` so that you could order directly on the user?

Comment: I'm not familiar with :touch. Looking at the documentation here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/touch would it just involve adding a :after_create callback on the messages model that does user.touch ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would probably be preferential to the solution mentioned by [phoet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100731/phoet) of adding an attribute to User such as `last_message_posted_at` and using `touch: true` to update that on message creation. That simplifies the query that has to be performed when you need to pull your list of users. This also allows a much more readable (IMO) chain for your application:

```
@users = User.all.order(:last_message_posted_at)
=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" ORDER BY \"users\".\"last_message_posted_at\" ASC"
```

This also allows you to add a nice and simple scope to your User model

```
scope: :by_recent_message, ->{ order(:last_message_posted_at) }
User.by_recent_message.limit(5)
```

It also depends when and how often this `@users` scope is being used. Adding a few ms to the message post time is preferable, to me, than a complicated SQL query each time the list of users is pulled.

**-- Edit for those who aren't familiar with the touch syntax --**

Documentation for touch: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, touch: true
end
```

And then make my query (to the user with most recent last message):

```
@user =  User.includes(:messages).order(updated_at: :desc )
```

Comment: I tried to edit your answer to add the exact syntax to use, but it was rejected. I added the answer below. If you include those points to your answer, I'll delete mine and accept your answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It offered me the chance to approve it - so its updated now. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along the lines of

```
Message.group(:user_id).joins(:users).order('max(messages.created_at) desc')
```

Comment: I get an error: "ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'users' was not found on Message; perhaps you misspelled it?" So I tried changing users to user in the joins and got a different error: "PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "messages.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: Yeah, you have to play with exact names of the fields, but the idea is there - use GROUP BY user and sort by aggregated field. Of course, I would vote for `last_posted_at` attribute as well, but if you wouldn't like to change the schema, this could be a single-query solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use left join instead of includes

```
@users = User.joins("LEFT JOIN messages on messages.user_id = users.id").order('messages.created_at').limit(5)
```

Comment: unfortunately, this returns duplicate users in @users.

Comment: Yes it will give you duplicate users because one user has many messages and we have used left join but you can use either group,distinct or uniq method to avoid duplicates.